# How to avoid loops in NGRX or NGXS

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngxs

I have a component like `user-personal-details.component.ts`. Which stays in sync with `user`  stored in `Store`

```
@Select() user$: Observable<IUser>;
user:IUser;
ngOnInit() {
  this.user$.subscribe((user:IUser)=>{
    this.user = user;
    this.form.form.patchValue(user);//LINE A: fill the form using user data
  };
}
```

This component has a form to fill details about the `user`. There is no save button, everytime user type of any of these component, I detect changes via

```
this.form.valueChanges.debounce(2000).subscribe((formData)=>{
    this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUser(formData));//Line B
})
```

and dispatch an `Action` named `UpdateUser` to store changes in `Store`.

**Problem:**

Problem is when user will type something, it will dispatch action to change User in store (**Line B**). Since component is subscribed to `user` in store, **Line A** will be called again. Which in turn, patch the form hence calling **Line B**. Thus making it a cycle.

One way to avoid this is mutate the state when form changes because that will not fire an action and hence line B will not be called. But I think thats not recommended in Redux.

Can someone suggest a more elegant way to deal with this problem?

Note: I am using NGXS for this but I guess it shouldn't make a difference.

**Edit**: Since the question was downvoted, I made a big edit to this question to make the problem minimal.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that you should populate the form with user from store only once at the beginning when form is loaded. Any later change of the user form shouldn't change the form anymore. The form will be source of truth in that case. It will not sync data *from* the store anymore but to the store.

You can use `take` operator for that:

```
this.user$.pipe(take(1)).subscribe((user:IUser)=>{
  this.user = user;
  this.form.form.patchValue(user);//LINE A: fill the form using user data
};
```

BTW also consider using [form plugin for NGXS](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/plugins/form)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I can't do that. I have a reset button which when clicked, discard all the user changes, and fills the forms with fresh server verison of the form.

Comment: @dasfdsa why you cant do that? So there is another button which fills data to the form and since then form is again source of truth. Its the same situation.

Comment: Thanks again. 1. reset button fetches the fresh data from server and stores it into the store.  2. Since component has subscribed to this.user$ it will again patch the form. 3. Since the form has been patched this.form.valueChanges will run its callback and dispatches the action to change the store. 4.  this callbac.user$ subscription callback will run....and the cycle continues. Sorry for the late response.

Comment: If I do this.user$.pipe(take(1)). My form will not be patched like its happening in step 2.

Comment: @dasfdsa when clicking reset it should reload the user and patch the form itself with reloaded data. You could event have a method `refreshFrom` which reload store from server and patches the form. But dont let the component listening for data all the time imho.

Comment: I could have. But what if there are multiple forms in various different component and I have a reset button in, say, header component? @Martin

Comment: in that case create an observable `resetForm$ = new Subject()` and use `resetForm$.next({ userdata... })` - this should be called only when you open the form or after pressing reset button. Subscribe to that and patch the form when subject emits. Could that work?

Comment: Yes. I think you are right. Can you write a line about how ngxs form plugin will help in this case. My current project makes heavy use of forms in the way I described. I have always been excited about ngxs forms plugin but not sure how to use it.

Comment: Basically it connects the form to the store. When you change something in the store it propagates to the form and vice versa when you change the form it changes the state. There is a debounce for that. If you decide to use that I think you would need a spot in your state like `edittedUser` which would be connected to the form and set when you reload the user or open form component.